# select bootstrap no funciona en movil

Tags: php, bootstrap, autocomplete

Tengo este código **Bootstrap** que autocompleta países por una base de datos **MYSQL**. Funciona correctamente, solo que, no se a que se debe pero cuando coloco el codigo en mi sitio, el espacio del select se queda como desactivado. Por si solo en otra pagina funciona correctamente.

Si pulso el botón para autocompletar, sí aparece el `<textbox>` para la búsqueda, pero en versión móvil no funciona. He quitado los `<navs>` y los `<div>` y nada mejora.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="description" content="red social">
      <title>My World</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
      <!-- slide epm -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/stye_epm.css">
      <!-- slide -->
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style_slide.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <!-- <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'> -->
      <!-- menu -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.11.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css'>
  </head>

   <body>

     <!-- Contenido -->    

        <!-- Formulario Login -->
        <div class="container">


        <div><h3>Mi Sitio</h3></div>

        <!-- Formulario Registro -->
        <button type='button' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#regPopUpWindow">Registrate</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="regPopUpWindow">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <!-- header -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Formulario de Registro</h3>
              </div>
              <!-- body -->
              <div class="modal-header">
                <form role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"/>
                    <!-- <input type="text" id="ciudades" required class="form-control" name="ciudades" class="form-control" placeholder="Ciudad" /> -->
                    <div class="container">
   <div class="row">

      <div class="row-fluid">
        <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith">

  <?php
  include "db.php";
  $con = connect();
  if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {//asignamos la codificación comprobando que no falle
         die("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8");
  }
  $consulta = "SELECT * FROM lista_paises";
  $resultado = mysqli_query($con , $consulta);
  $contador=0;

  while($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ $contador++;?>
  <option data-subtext="<?php echo $misdatos["iso"]; ?>"><?php echo $misdatos["nombre_pais"]; ?></option>
  <?php }?>          
  </select>

      </div><hr />
      </div> 

    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
              <!-- footer -->
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Registrarse</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p></p>

      <!-- partial -->
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
      <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Funciona de maravilla, sin embargo me gustaría saber como puedo colocar esos valores desde un archivo externo, mm no sé un **JSON**.

¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como sale, y al pulsar el botón y escribir, si aparece la lista, pero en equipos de escritorio, móvil no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así funciona correctamente, en cuanto pulso *click* sale la lista, para móvil y escritorio.

Comment: Estás haciendo varias preguntas en una sóla, además no queda del todo claro qué es lo que funciona y qué es lo que no.

Comment: Con todo y la edición de la pregunta, ¿alguna sugerencia?.
En este instante tengo en modo local el ejemplo y funciona correctamente, pero al subirlo al sitio web el cuadro de buscar no aparece en versión movil.

Comment: El recuadro de texto que aparece en la lista para escribir el nombre del país no se visualiza en versión movil.

Comment: Podrías compartir el sitio web para que podamos probar el error que mencionas?

Comment: claro mira, al pulsar registro, aparece el usuario y la contraseña, pero al elegir la ciudad no permite escribir si estas en celular, si es equipo de escritorio tampoco aparece el textbox pero si pulsas una letra si se muestra la lista. https://bit.ly/2kYp1jz

Comment: nadie?, en localhost funciona bien el popup de bootstrap y el autobuscador, pero en el sitio web no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al no recibir respuesta alguna, fui depurando y al parecer como tengo bootstrap y algunos efectos, tal parece que es un JS que genera conflicto con algunas otras librerías, he escrito el código linea por linea y ahora ya funciona, tengo 200 mil registros en la BD y también tiene algunos caracteres erroneos.

Ahora funciona bien, el problema es que está muy lenta la búsqueda, por lo tanto buscaré la forma de hacerlo con AJAX y JSON.